# Regex expression to replace characters between two options

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create an elegant regular expression to replace the following string:

`12:00:00 a. m.`
to this: 
`12:00 AM`

or also replace:
`12:00:23 a.m.` to `12:00 am`

I mean, I want to delete the last ones: `:00` and replace `a. m.` by `AM`

This is what I thought (but is missing):

```
"12:00:00 a. m.".replace(/(:*)?(.*\s)/, "");
```

Thanks a lot for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with two capturing groups to do it in a single `replace`:

`/:\d\d\s*(\w)\.?\s*(\w)\.?/`

```js
const func = str => str.replace(/:\d\d\s*(\w)\.?\s*(\w)\.?/, (a, b, c) => {
  return ` ${b}${c}`.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(func('12:12:34 a. m.'));
console.log(func('12:34:56 a.m.'));
console.log(func('12:12:34 pm'));
console.log(func('12:34:56pm'));
console.log(func('12:34:56p.   m'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It partly depends how general you want to be, but this seems to work:

```js
function replaceTime(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}/, "$1")
            .replace(/\s*a\.*\s*m\.*/, " AM");
}
console.log(replaceTime("12:00:00 a. m."));
console.log(replaceTime("12:00:23 a.m"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are not doing any validation work here. This way two chained `raplece()` methods will do the job:

```
str.replace(/^(.*):\d+/, '$1')
    .replace(/([a-z])[. ]*/g, ($0, $1) => $1.toUpperCase())
```

Above works for `p. m.` or `pm`.

ES5:

```js
console.log("12:00:00 a. m.".replace(/^(.*):\d+/, '$1')
        .replace(/([a-z])[. ]*/g, function($0, $1) { return $1.toUpperCase(); }))
```